# Spring boot error org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, mariadb

Run the Jar package the spring boot application with data spring jpa and the mysql connector have different results in the Windows 10 environment and the linuxmint environment.

If this application runs on linuxmint it works perfectly, but if it starts in Windows 10 an error like this occurs:

```
ERROR org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: 
[PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: 
Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
```

this is  pom.xml dependencies

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>8.40.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.jensd</groupId>
            <artifactId>fontawesomefx</artifactId>
            <version>8.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfxtras</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfxtras-all</artifactId>
            <version>8.0-r5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

And this application.properties

```
# datasourcce
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/apotekfxboot
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

# hibernate
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Note:
Both of these environments use the same mariadb version, which is 10.1.19.
Coding is done in the linuxmint environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

to

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: you are right, thank you for the answer, this answer must also be accompanied by the addition of the time zone on like this

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/apotekfxboot?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC